# Query on a column of string of an object where x key is a y value Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a column called type that the value could be an object as a string, for example:

```
type = "{ 'a' : 'test1', 'b' : 'test2' }";
```

I want to get using Eloquent all rows where `type.b = "test";`

I can't access `b` in my where statement as it's not a column variable. I know I can use regex for it but I want to see if there is a better approach.

Comment: A better approach is to normalise your data to make them relational, which means create relationships between this table and `a` and `b` as separate tables. If you don't want to have normalised relational data (which would also raise the question as to why you are using a relational database) you should at least convert that data to a portable format like JSON so you can use MySQLs [JSON column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) and [related functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html)

Comment: is `type` a json column? i dont think eloquent support json column functionality out of the box. query builder did support `where` on json. anyway, you could use `like` operator on `where` as workaround if you want to stick with eloquent. or you could just shove `whereRaw` somewhere.

Comment: @BagusTesa Laravel does support [JSON where queries](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#json-where-clauses) but the data here is not actually valid JSON

Comment: @apokryfos eloquent != query builder. though they share some functionalities. mixing them is ok. but, i do find some dev so vehement on using eloquent.

Comment: @apokryfos This isn't a new table rather than an old one and changing it could result in bugs

Comment: @apokryfos can you share what is a valid J for eloquent

Comment: @Zein those `a` and `b` should be enclosed in single quotes. just like their values.

Comment: @BagusTesa oh my bad they are I will edit the post

Comment: @BagusTesa Eloquent is the ORM but it does extend the query builder for queries so all query builder features are also available to the eloquent query builder

Comment: @Zein You can validate JSON at https://jsonlint.com/ in your case valid JSON would be `{ "a": "test1", "b": "test2" }` or as a PHP string `'{ "a": "test1", "b": "test2" }'`

Answer (score 0):

You should add `"casts"` in your Model like this

```
protected $casts = [
        'type' => 'array'
    ];
```

And after it you can access `b` like this

```
$model->type['b'];
```